# Flex XML from Obix

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash-builder

with the below xml   I'm trying to get the val  from the "real" name=sum element.

everything I try won't get me past the "obj" level  (not the root "obj" level)

I'm working with flex 4.5

```
  <obj href="http://10.1.151.163/obix/histories/Dashboard_ENC/WaterConsumtion/~historyRollup/" is="obix:HistoryQueryOut" xsi:schemaLocation="http://obix.org/ns/schema/1.0 /obix/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://obix.org/ns/schema/1.0">
     <list name="data" of="obix:HistoryRollupRecord">
        <obj>
          <abstime name="start" val="2011-06-13T10:00:00.000-04:00" tz="EDT"/>
          <abstime name="end" val="2011-06-13T11:00:00.000-04:00" tz="EDT"/>
          <int name="count" val="4"/>
          <real name="min" val="0.0"/>
          <real name="max" val="25.0"/>
          <real name="avg" val="14.105714559555054"/>
          <real name="sum" val="56.422858238220215"/>
       </obj>
       <obj>
         <abstime name="start" val="2011-06-13T11:00:00.000-04:00" tz="EDT"/>
         <abstime name="end" val="2011-06-13T12:00:00.000-04:00" tz="EDT"/>
         <int name="count" val="4"/>
         <real name="min" val="12.38690185546875"/>
         <real name="max" val="42.49167251586914"/>
         <real name="avg" val="29.935394763946533"/>
         <real name="sum" val="119.74157905578613"/>
       </obj>
   </list>
      <int name="count" val="2"/>
      <abstime name="start" val="2011-06-13T10:00:00.000-04:00" tz="EDT"/>
     <abstime name="end" val="2011-06-13T12:00:00.000-04:00" tz="EDT"/>
  </obj>
```

here is what I have ...

```
private function parseWater(ev:Event):void
{       
    var _xmlWater:XML = new XML(ev.target.data);

    trace(_xmlWater);                       
    trace(_xmlWater..obj[1].real[3].@val);  // <-- this doesn't work -- undefined 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably don't want to use the 'int' tag since that's a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
_xmlWater.list[0].obj[1].real[3].@val;
```

Comment: nope,                                                             TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Comment: Ah, it works if I use [Namespaces](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Namespace.html) properly.  I didn't see that your original XML had a namespace.

Comment: 'private function parseWater(ev:Event):void
    
   {  
  
    var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(ev.target.data.toString());
    var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
    var resultObj:Object = decoder.decodeXML(xmlDoc);
       
    trace(resultObj.obj.list.obj[1].real[2].val); 
       
   }'   seems to work.   Don't really follow you on the Namespace thing.

Comment: Did you even look at the link?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have the node "list" in there. It kinda looks like you just made a typo however and the code you ran actually did refer to "list".

Here's a really detailed explanation of how to work with XML data in AS3:

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/using_xml_as3_pg1.htm

Comment: from the article I tried .. private function parseWater(ev:Event):void { var _xmlWater:XML = new XML(ev.target.data); ParseObj(_xmlWater); } private function ParseObj(MyObj:XML):void { trace("XML Output"); trace("------------------------"); trace(MyObj); trace("------------------------"); trace(MyObj.list.obj); } In the console everything as expected until trace(MyObj.list.obj) then just blank line.

Comment: I think it may be something with the xml.   Not sure what, flex doesn't like the element names??  I can't change them.